# What is the (API name) Edit Date field in Leadhistory Report

Tags: apex

In the LeadHistory report type, there is a field called edit date. Can i query on this field and want to use it on Apex class? i want see all the leads which have edit_date in last month. I cant seem to find this field in Leadhistory

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_leadhistory.htm
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Edit Date" you're mentioning actually is the CreatedDate field on the Lead History object.

On reports this appears as "Edit Date" because the history is created upon lead edition.

In my opinion you can either use the CreatedDate on the Lead History object or the LastModifiedDate field directly on the Lead object.

Comment: Makes sense.. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Not particularilly, though I found a reference here pointing to this direction: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hIfDAAU